# OpenCV 2.4.0 C++ goodFeaturesToTrack corrupts heap?

Tags: c++, opencv, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm just now starting to learn how to use the openCV libraries. I've downloaded and installed openCV 2.4.0, and have run a few example projects. In this block of code, I'm trying to get the output from goodFeaturesToTrack and plot the points on an image. The code compiles, but every time I run it, it crashes, and I get the following error:

---

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Corner.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Corner.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Corner.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

---

The output window does not have more diagnostic information. I've traced the error to the goodFeaturesToTrack function. Here's the offending code:

```
// Corner.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv_modules.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv; //If you don't have this, you won't be able to create a mat...
using namespace std;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

//Whole bunch of #defines to make editing the code a lot easier

#define MAX_FEATURES 5
#define FILENAME "C:/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/lol.jpg"

int main(void)
{
    namedWindow("Out", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("In", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
    Mat Img;
    Img = cvLoadImage(FILENAME, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if(!Img.data)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Couldn't open picture.");
        waitKey();
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        imshow("In", Img);
        waitKey();
    }

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> Img_features;
    int number_of_features = MAX_FEATURES;

    Mat Out = Mat::zeros(Img.cols, Img.rows, CV_32F);

    goodFeaturesToTrack(Img, Img_features, MAX_FEATURES, .01, .1, noArray(), 3, false);

    fprintf(stdout, "Got here...");

    /*for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FEATURES; i++)
    {
        Point2f p = Img_features[i];
        ellipse(Img, p, Size(1,1), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255,0,0));
    }*/

    imshow("Out", Out);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;


}
```

Is this a bug in the library, or am I doing something dumb?

Comment: Why are you displaying `Out` in the end if you are not using it anywhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `Img_features` vector should have `MAX_FEATURES` items before calling goodFeatures? i.e. try `Img_features.resize(MAX_FEATURES)` before goodFeatures call.

Comment: That seemed to help, now I have another problem: when I attempt to return, the program crashes again, now with this message:

Unhandled exception at 0x779815de in Corner.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x443ec000.

Thanks for solving that earlier problem

Comment: It won't have any effect whether you resize the vector or not.
`goodFeaturesToTrack` automatically resizes the vector to the number of features found in the image.

Comment: @pYr0 If you using Visual Studio, enable exception handling (Alt+E), break on it - and you will determine problem source.

Comment: @sgar91 Really? As i know, OpenCV usually use their own array type in functions parameters. It can constructs from `std::vector`, but later it will work with it as with fixed size array.

Comment: Actually its not "their own array type" . `cv::InputArray` and `cv::OutputArray` is a generic array type interface implemented in OpenCV. It can be a `cv::Mat` or `std::vector` etc. If you don't believe me, try it out yourself. The vector will automatically be resized.

Comment: @sgar91 Ok, but in this case why OP have such problems. So, you think that vector size isn't the reason of them?

Comment: No, the code is running ok. I think the issue would be that may be @pYr0 is linking the libraries incorrectly. Memory issues are caused when `Release` mode libraries are linked in `Debug` configuration or vice versa.

Comment: @sgar91 You were right. Looking at my linker files, I was linking all of the wrong ones (i.e. opencv_core240.lib instead of opencv_core240d.lib). Also, after commenting out the .resize line, the code still works as well. Thanks for helping me out with my (dumb) questions!